# Consulta SQL com SUM, exibindo o retorno em linhas

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Então turma possuo uma dúvida que está consumindo minhas entranhas. Alguém por obséquio saberia me dizer como retornar um total de registros de uma consulta, via função SUM (SQL Server), exibindo o total de linhas proporcionais ao número de registros ao invés do valor agregado que a função faz?

Exemplificando pela SUM: adquiro a quantidade total de dinheiro (apenas tomando-o como exemplo), e para esse montante exibo-o em linhas / registros, suponhamos que tenha um total de R$500,00, desta forma teria que exibir 500 linhas (1,2,3,4... até 500).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou assumir a existência de uma tabela que contém os valores numéricos:

```
CREATE TABLE #Tabela
(
    Codigo        INT,
    Montante      FLOAT,
)

INSERT INTO #Tabela(Codigo, Montante)VALUES
(1, 4),
(1, 2),
(2, 6),
(2, 1),
(3, 3),
(4, 2)
```

A soma dos montantes pode ser obtida através da seguinte query:

```
SELECT Codigo, SUM(Montante) Soma
FROM   #Tabela
GROUP BY Codigo
```

Para gerar o número de linhas proporcional ao valor da soma para cada código, uma alternativa é a seguinte:

```
;WITH TodasAsSomas AS
(
    SELECT Codigo, SUM(Montante) Soma, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(Montante) DESC) RN
    FROM   #Tabela
    GROUP BY Codigo
),
Linhas AS
(
    SELECT 1 numL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT numL + 1
    FROM Linhas
    WHERE numL <= (SELECT Soma FROM TodasAsSomas WHERE RN = 1) 
)
SELECT S.Codigo, S.Soma, L.numL
FROM   TodasAsSomas S
INNER JOIN Linhas L
    ON L.numL <= S.Soma
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Resultado:

```
Codigo  Soma    numL
1       6       1
1       6       2
1       6       3
1       6       4
1       6       5
1       6       6
2       7       1
2       7       2
2       7       3
2       7       4
2       7       5
2       7       6
2       7       7
3       3       1
3       3       2
3       3       3
4       2       1
4       2       2
```

- Atenção que a soma pode resultar num número decimal; pode ser necessário arredondar o resultado para obter o número desejado de linhas;
- Se o objectivo é gerar o número de linhas que corresponde à soma de todos os valores (sem agrupar por um código/chave), apenas é necessário remover a coluna 'Codigo' e a cláusula GROUP BY, por exemplo:

```
;WITH SomaTotal AS
(
    SELECT SUM(Montante) Soma
    FROM   #Tabela
),
Linhas AS
(
    SELECT 1 numL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT numL + 1
    FROM Linhas
    WHERE numL <= (SELECT Soma FROM SomaTotal) 
)
SELECT S.Soma, L.numL
FROM   SomaTotal S
INNER JOIN Linhas L
    ON L.numL <= S.Soma
ORDER BY 1, 2
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Resultado:

```
Soma    numL
18      1
18      2
18      3
18      4
18      5
18      6
18      7
18      8
18      9
18      10
18      11
18      12
18      13
18      14
18      15
18      16
18      17
18      18
```

Comment: Good Job... Fiquei matutando hoje no trabalho um bom tempo, e não encontrei uma solução. Obrigado @Bruno.

Comment: De nada @JuniorFerreiraDoNascimento!